# Lightning Button Disable in Mobile Device

Tags: lightning

I have created a Lightning component where I have a Button. The code snippet is as below. I want to disable this button in Mobile. Is there any way to disable in mobile device?

```
<lightning:button title="Button action" aura:id="create_button" class="slds-button slds-button_brand" label="{!$Label.c.createAccountButton}" disabled="{!v.createAccButton}" onclick="{!c.getAccountDetails}"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do like this:

```
<lightning:button title="Button action" aura:id="create_button" class="slds-button slds-button_brand" label="{!$Label.c.createAccountButton}" disabled="{!$Browser.formFactor eq 'PHONE'}" onclick="{!c.getAccountDetails}"/>
```

Note use of $Browser global.

You can combine with your existing logic like so:

```
disabled ="{! or(v.createAccButton,$Browser.formFactor eq 'PHONE')}"
```